# Infinite Loop in Ember-Data clearRelationships?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

**Inquiry:**
Can anybody tell me why I might be getting an infinite loop when attempting to delete an Ember-Data Model.  Stepping through the crash, the issue appears to be in clearRelationships, but no matter how minimal I attempt to make the Model relationships I can't seem to get away from the infinite loop, without avoiding them all together.

---

**Relevant Code:**

```
//// Config
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();
App.store = DS.Store.create({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: App.Adapter.create()
});
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({});
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('main', { path: '/' });
});

//// Models
App.Scientist = DS.Model.extend({
  name:     DS.attr('string'),
  tests:    DS.hasMany('App.Tests'),
  criteria: DS.belongsTo('App.Criteria')
});
App.Test = DS.Model.extend({
  name:      DS.attr('string'),
  scientist: DS.belongsTo('App.Scientist'),
  criteria:  DS.belongsTo('App.Criteria')
});
App.Criteria = DS.Model.extend({
  name:      DS.attr('string'),
  scientist: DS.belongsTo('App.Scientist'),
  test:      DS.belongsTo('App.Test'),
  resources: DS.hasMany('App.Resource')
});
App.Resource = DS.Model.extend({
  name:     DS.attr('string'),
  criteria: DS.belongsTo('App.Criteria')
});

//// Pre-Load Models
App.store.loadMany(App.Test,
  [{id:'1', scientist_id:'1', name:'gravity', criteria_id:'2'},
   {id:'2', scientist_id:'1', name:'not gravity', criteria_id:'3'}]);
App.store.load(App.Scientist, 
  {id:'1', name:'Bill', tests:['1', '2'], criteria_id:'1'});
App.store.load(App.Criteria, 
  {id:'1', name:'control', scientist_id:'1', test_id:null, resources:['1']});
App.store.loadMany(App.Criteria,
  [{id:'2', name:'variation1', scientist_id:null, test_id:'1', resources:['2','3']},
   {id:'3', name:'variation2', scientist_id:null, test_id:'2', resources:['4','5']}]);
App.store.loadMany(App.Resource, 
  [{id:'1', name:'resource1', criteria_id:'1'},
   {id:'2', name:'resource2', criteria_id:'2'},
   {id:'3', name:'resource3', criteria_id:'2'},
   {id:'4', name:'resource4', criteria_id:'3'},
   {id:'5', name:'resource5', criteria_id:'3'}]);

var filter = App.Test.filter(
  function(model) { if (model.get('isLoaded') === true) { return model; } }
);

App.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('tests', filter);
  }
});

///// Controller
App.MainController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  name: 'Main',
  createTest: function() {
    App.Test.createRecord();
    App.store.commit();
  },
  removeTest: function(test) {
    test.deleteRecord();
    App.store.commit();
  }
});
```

---

**Steps to Reproduce:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hilem/GMt7H/

1) Open Browser Console.
2) Run the fiddle.
3) Watch console as you hit remove on one of the list items.

---

**Update 1 (8:44PM 1/27/2013)**
Additional Context: This is using ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js && the latest commit of ember-data on master as of 1/27/2013.  I also added a bit more to the example code above.

---

**Update 2 (5:25PM 2/1/2013)**
Bump! Issue still exists, there seems to be quite a few issues involving deleteRecord lately on github issue tracker that sound similar to my issue.  Here's a link to my specific issue on the tracker:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/671

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. This pull request on Github fixed it for me. https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/715

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I had models like these

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  account: DS.belongsTo('App.Account'),
  name: DS.attr('string')

});

App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
  type: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The recursion isn't actually happening in clearRelationships but in this section of the ember.js set method

```
var meta = obj[META_KEY], desc = meta && meta.descs[keyName],
      isUnknown, currentValue;
  if (desc) {
    desc.set(obj, keyName, value);
  } else {
   ....
  }
```

when I deleted the User it tried to clearRelationships which calls `set(this, "account", null)` which eventually gets to the section above which calls set again and again and again.

I'm not sure the right way to fix this but I got it to work in my situation by removing the user belongsTo relationship on the account. so my new models look like this

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  account: DS.belongsTo('App.Account'),
  name: DS.attr('string')

});

App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
  // user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
  type: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: on second thought this obviously isn't a solution because without having the user on the account you lose access to the related information