# ember adapter issues

Tags: javascript, recursion, ember.js, ember-data

I have set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahnrs/) to demonstrate the problem I am having trying to learn Ember.js

I have these models:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    account: DS.belongsTo('App.Account')
});

App.Account = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('App.User'),
    transactions: DS.hasMany('App.Transaction'),
    balance: function() {
      return this.get('transactions').getEach('amount').reduce(function(accum, item) {
          return accum + item;
      }, 0);
  }.property('transactions.@each.amount')
});

App.Transaction = DS.Model.extend({
    account: DS.belongsTo('App.Account'),
    amount: DS.attr('number'),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Using the FixtureAdapter the Account loads it's hasMany transactions but not its belongsTo user.

Using the RESTAdapter the Account loads it's relationships fine but it gives the error Too much recursion when I try to delete it.

Can anyone help me solve these issues? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue you were having the FixtureAdapter. Your Account fixtures had a *user_id* property instead of just *user* with the id as the value.

```
App.Account.FIXTURES = [
{
    id: 10001,
    user: 1,
    transactions: [1, 2, 3]
}
];
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ianpetzer/pGeGw/

With regards to the recursive problems you are experiencing with the RestAdapter... I might very possibly be wrong ...but I think this is a bug with ember-data.

See these links:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/671

[Infinite Loop in Ember-Data clearRelationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552589/infinite-loop-in-ember-data-clearrelationships)